# Reduce $\int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\ g(t-s)dtds$ to a single integral

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that:
$$\int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\ g(t-s)dtds = \int^{T}_{-T}\ (T-|\tau|)g(\tau)d\tau$$

We need to set $\tau = t-s$ and $\sigma = t+s$. (We basically shift the cartesian coordinaets by 45 degrees (?))

So, $t=\frac{\sigma+\tau}{2}$ and $s = \frac{\sigma-\tau}{2}$.

My main problems are: the Jacobian (I calculated it but based on some examples I think I am wrong) and how the factor $(T-|\tau|)$ will appear.

I have seen that similar questions with answers exist but I have not found one that I understood fully.

Comment: What was the Jacobian you calculated?

Comment: Write the double integral in terms of $d\sigma\, d\tau$. What are the bounds of $\sigma$ given a certain $\tau$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi without an absolute value the Jacobian was -1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach. Change the variable $s$ to $u$ with $u=t-s$. Then, $du=-ds$ and

$$I=\int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\ g(t-s)dtds 
= \int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\int^{t+\frac{T}{2}}_{t-\frac{T}{2}}\ g(u)du dt\\
=  \int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\int^{t+\frac{T}{2}}_{0}\ g(u)du dt
 + \int^{\frac{T}{2}}_{-\frac{T}{2}}\int^{0}_{t-\frac{T}{2}}\ g(u)du dt
  $$

which corresponds to the integration over two triangular regions, one above the $t$-axis and the other below. Now, exchange the order of the integration between $t$ and $u$

\begin{align}
I
= & \int^{{T}}_{0}\int_{u-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac T2}\ g(u)dt du 
+ \int^{0}_{-T}\int_{-\frac T2}^{u+\frac{T}{2}}\ g(u)dtdu\\
= &\int^{{T}}_{0}(T-u) g(u)du+ \int_{{-T}}^{0}(T+u) g(u)du
=\int^{T}_{-T}\ (T-|u|)g(u)du
\end{align}

Comment: So by just changing only one variable we do not need to use the Jacobian, right?

Comment: @DontWorry - correct; an alternative metnod

Comment: After substituting a "-" sign appears from du=-ds. In a double integral do we only need to reverse the values of the one integral? Must it be the inner one?